# how to get random number generator working in batch, tied with goto statement

Tags: batch-file

so, im trying to make a "chat" bot via batch, to make it seem more... interactive i have random responses, my idea is using a random number generator and if its greater or less than a max/min value it gauges the responses accordingly.

```
:numbergenerator1
set MinVal=1006
set MaxVal=20000
set /a RandomNumber= %random% / 30
set /a RandomNumber= %RandomNumber% + %MinVal%
if /i %RandomNumber% gtr %MinVal% goto help1 
else goto help2
if /i %RandomNumber% gtr %MaxVal% goto help3
else goto help4
```

^^^ is the latest test, however the first iteration of this is below

```
:numbergenerator1
set MinVal=708
set MaxVal=1098
set /a RandomNumber= %random% / 20
set /a RandomNumber= %RandomNumber% + %MinVal%
if /i %RandomNumber% GTR %Maxval% goto help2
if /i %RandomNumber% lss %MinVal% goto help1
if /i %RandomNumber% gtr %MinVal% goto help3
if /i %RandomNumber% lss %MaxVal% goto help4
```

what keeps happening is, ill run it and it will only use 1 response (help2 etc. are just sections with small bits of dialogue until i fully flesh them out)

Comment: Explain to me why you would use the /I option with the `IF` command when comparing integers? Open up a command prompt and type `IF /?` to read the help file. The `ELSE` syntax is clearly defined in the help.

Comment: I think, your logic is flawed. `help1` can never happen (`minval` plus a positive number can never be smaller than `minval`). `help4` will show up quite rarely (only when `random` happens to be `0` (`gtr minval` stops the show for every other value)). (I'm speaking of the last code snippet (`first iteration`)

Comment: Your `if`/`else` syntax is wrong; type `if /?` into a Command Prompt window and learn how it works…

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are not using the variable `randomnumber` for another purpose elsewhere in your script, your logic could be simplified to:

```
For /f "Delims=" %%v in ('Set /A %Random% %% 4 + 1')Do Goto:help%%v
```